# Как поставить свои сертификаты на Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

Мучаюсь уже целый день. Не могу загрузить, говорит что надо заплатить 200$/месяц. Может кто ставил?

Comment: Заплатите 200$/месяц и ставьте

Comment: В документации же прямо написано: [Domains on Business and Enterprise plans are allowed Custom SSL certificates](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170466-Managing-Custom-SSL-certificates). Если у вас Free или Pro, то покупайте сертификат в Cloudflare